# I want to create a cloud web application however I don't want to my in database in cloud. Can I keep my datasource in local machine

Tags: database, datasource, local, device, desktop

I want to create a cloud application however my database contains sensitive information and don't want to keep it in IBM cloud. Is it possible that my data source remains on my local machine and my cloud application uses data source from my desktop. Running the application 24X7 is not the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely possible to do this.

If your system has a public ip it should be pretty straightforward- just use the public up and configure your application to connect to it.

If you don’t have a public ip- What you would need to do is connect to you on premise system using a secure gateway - https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/services/secure-gateway and that would essentially establish a tunnel into your private environment.